# Access Token from JavaScript API

Tags: facebook, access-token

I'm working on a small game, where the user can play one time each day. I will track this via the `Facebook ID`.

All the backend is done, and the game works when I manually insert my `Facebook ID` and `access token`.... But how do I get the `access token` from the Facebook API?

I tried this:

```
FB.init({ 
            appId: 'my app id', 
            channelURL : '//my domain/channel.html', // Channel File
            cookie: true, 
            xfbml: true, 
            status: true 
        });

        FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
            if (response.session) {
                alert(response.session.access_token);
            } else {
                alert("not logged in");
            }
        });
```

But it always alerted "Not logged in", even if I'm logged into Facebook.

(My domain and app ID is hidden due to privacy of my client)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should definatly [Migrate to oAuth2](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/oauth2-https-migration/), (if you haven't - you should),
then you can try this :

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse && response.status=="connected") {
        uid = response.authResponse.userID;
        token = response.authResponse.accessToken;
        // user is logged in
    }
});
```

For the javascript SDK all you have to do in order to migrate to oAuth2 is add an additional parameter to the initialization : 
`oauth : true`